# Using html in javascript trouble?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi guys I'm having trouble getting my code to correctly display html within the javascript code I have. basically, I am checking for the variable hundo to equal 3 and then have the script display a form. I have tested the code to just show an alert message when hundo equals 3, but when I use document.write it fails to work. My guess is the problem lies there...

```
<script>
setInterval(function(){
if(hundo == '3'){
document.open();
document.write("<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Link URL: <input type="text" name="linkurl" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>");
document.close();
}
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alternate the quotes you are using in your `document.write`:

```
document.write('<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Link URL: <input type="text" name="linkurl" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>');
```

The problem is that you are only using one type of quotes, so javascript sees `"<form action="` than an undefined javascript object: `insert.php`, without any operator between them, to boot.

Comment: What you say makes complete sense and yet it is still not working.

Comment: "it is still not working" - meaning _what_ exactly? What does the error console say?

Comment: The error console says nothing the form just doesn't show up when hundo = 3.

Comment: @user1126681 - Where do you expect it to appear? `document.write` would end up at the top of the document. You should probably use the DOM instead of `document.write`, constructing the elements in memory and appending to a known node.

Comment: Oh I did not realize that it would show up at the top of the document, how would I go about showing the form where it is coded into the <body> tags?

Comment: @user1126681 - Several ways, but using the DOM is (in my opinion) best. An alternative is to have a `div` with an id, use `document.getElementById` using that id and setting the `innerHTML` property to the new form.

Comment: Sorry I'm still somewhat new to javascript what is DOM and how would i use it?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is the string in your document.write is closing itself, try enclosing it in ''

```
<script>
setInterval(function(){
 if(hundo == '3'){
 document.open();
 document.write('<form action="insert.php" method="post">
  Link URL: <input type="text" name="linkurl" />
  <input type="submit" />
 </form>');
 document.close();
}
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
setInterval(function(){
if(hundo == '3'){
document.open();
document.write('<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Link URL: <input type="text" name="linkurl" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>');
document.close();
}
}, 1000);
</script>
```

This will work..:)